# Keep getting error in Anypoint studio about connecting salesforce

Tags: salesforce, anypoint-studio, mulesoft

[error code i am receiving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rFLGB.png)
I am currently trying to connect my Salesforce account with Anypoint studio for Mulesoft practice.  I consistently get the same error.

I have tried resetting my token and i know the password is correct.

Answer (score 0):

This does not mean your SFDC credentials are incorrect. It means your tooling service in Anypoint Studio has an issue.

To try and remedy go to menu:
Studio -> Preferences/Setttings(on windows?) -> Anypoint Studio -> Tooling and choose 'Restart Instance'

If that does not remedy:

Studio -> Window -> Show view -> Other  and search for 'Error Log'.  There will contain any errors that may be causing the tooling to fail.